# How to write "from among these [items], we discuss..." correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I'm struggling with the correct way to express myself here. Suppose I have a list of items in one sentence. In the next sentence, I want to express that I select some of these to talk about in detail. It would be something like this:

> Some examples of fruits are apple, banana, cherry, and durian. **From among these**, we discuss cherry and durian in detail.

Of course, this is incorrect English. What would be a correct one though?

*The text is in academic style.*

Comment: Simply 'of these' would be perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Apples bananas, cherries, and durians are examples of fruits. In this paper, we discuss the cherry and the durian in detail. [I would never start a paper with: Some examples of x are.] And it is not necessary to use awkward phrasing.

Comment: Just a note to expand on @Lambie's point: "academic style" does not have to mean that more complicated is better or that simpler is worse. It simply means to avoid any usages that are not accepted by academic style. Many everyday expressions are perfectly valid and are preferable to more stilted alternatives.